# Does entities managed by an Entity Manager have 2 objects in heap memory?

Tags: jpa, entity

In my DAO class, let's say, I have Entity Manager 'em' made out of an Entity Manager Factory, the code after that goes as follows:-

```
CarEntity carEntity = new CarEntity;//line 1
carEntity.setName("XYZ");           //line 2
```

When I execute the above lines of code, an object is created in heap memory and inside that, the value of its instance variables "XYZ" is stored.

Now consider the below code:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(carEntity);         //line 3
```

After line 3, as we know, carEntity object goes to managed state.
It will not goto database **until I flush or commit** the transaction.

So how does the Entity Manager knows that an entity has gone into managed state ?
Is there a new object created for CarEntity after `line 3` is executed ?
Or is there any change in its memory location in heap that signifies its change of state from 'new state' to 'managed state'?

AFAIK, the entities which are in managed state are assigned memory in persistent context (which is also an area of heap). So does it mean, that the memory is allocated again to the managed entities in heap.

If that is true, it would mean that a managed entity has 2 objects in heap memory of JVM. One handled by the reference from the program and another by the Entity Manager instance.

This is just what I want to clarify!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you add an entity to a List? The List just has a reference to the entity. It's the same thing for the persistence context. It keeps a reference to the managed entities. It knows an entity is managed because the entity is inside its collection of managed entities.

Comment: And is this reference called first level cache in case of Hibernate ? Please clarify

Comment: The session, i.e. the collection of references to managed entities, is the first-level cache.

Comment: So it means there is only one object in heap and after persist, the Entity Manager has a reference to this object. So what I understood is that to whatever entities Entity Manager has a reference belongs to the 'Persistence Context' and they are called as being in Managed state in JPA and Hibernate and also 1st level cache in Hibernate. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The implementation is free to do whatever it needs to do to do what it needs to do. That *might* include copying the state of the entity at the time of the insert, to detect if the entity has been modify afterwards. But it must keep a reference to the original entity, since it must return it whenever you call find() or execute a query that returns that entity. Why do you care?